# intersection of a 3D scalar field and a plane

Tags: 3d, plot, intersection, plane

I need to plot slices of a 3D scalar fields. For example, I have a file with the format:

```
x1, y1, z1, f1
x2, y2, z2, f2
...
```

where fs are scalars and x, y, z are coordinates (z is the fastest coordinate). I want to get points of an intersection between this 3D data and some plane and then to feed them to matplotlib. But first off I need to interpolate the data... Could you please tell me how to do that? Probably there are some links on the subject.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are your input points in a regular grid?

Comment: yes, points are in a regular grid

Answer (score 0):

For interpolation, use griddata from scipy.interpolate:

[Griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy-interpolate-griddata)

This page features a very nice example, and the signature of the function is really close to your data.

You still have to somehow define the points on you plane for which you want to interpolate the data. If you have a function of the form x,y->z describing your plane, you could use np.mgrid:

x_values, y_values = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
z_values = plane_function(x_values, y_values)

and use these as input for griddata.

Nevertheless, for cases like these maybe VTK (or for Python, TVTK and [MayaVi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/)), are better options. The have optimized algorithms for 3d-data and can offer interactive cut planes you can drag through volumetric data. I use VTK in my program [PyLocator](http://pylocator.thorstenkranz.de/index.html) which (among other things) does exactly this.